# Is converting array values to class properties resource intensive?

Tags: php

I have an array with approximately 50 keys & values. I would like to take the array and create class properties from the values like so:

```
$arr = array();
$arr['name'] = 'John';
$arr['age'] = '20';

$object = (object) $arr;

echo $object->name;
```

My question is, is this very resource-intensive? Would it require a lot of overhead with a large array? If so, would there be a better way of doing this?

Also, this does not work if the array is setup like:

```
$arr = array();
$arr['name']['boy'] = 'John';
$arr['name']['girl'] = 'Jane';
$arr['age']['boy'] = '20';
$arr['age']['girl'] = '30';

$object = (object) $arr;

echo $object->name->boy;
```

Comment: Have you benchmarked it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make like this :

```
$arr = array();

$arr['name']['boy'] = 'John';
$arr['name']['girl'] = 'Jane';
$arr['age']['boy'] = '20';
$arr['age']['girl'] = '30';


$obj = json_decode(json_encode($arr)); //Turn it into an object


print_r($obj);    // to view the result

echo $obj->name->boy;   // output: John
```

It works great with simple arrays and with subarrays too.

I think this is good solution when we work with subarrays and we want to save resources

Comment: Please read the title and think if this post answers the question: *Is converting array values to class properties resource intensive?*

Comment: It's is about conversion overhead. Please read question carefully before posting an answer.

Comment: I have readed it, but there was  question also about subarrays: 
"Also, this does not work if the array is setup like:"  
and I have written the best solution -  when we work with subarrays  and we want saving resources

Comment: This answer answers the second part of the question, why casting a nested array into an object does not work. The answer to the main question is simply "yes". It does not ask "how much". Imho this answer is valid.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.object.php) an object of type stdClass is created. My guess is, that copy-on-write will not work. A short experiment with `memory_get_usage()` showed the following results (three different scripts):

```
$arr=range(10,10000); $obj = $arr; var_dump(memory_get_usage()); // int(1717424)
$obj=(object)range(10,10000); var_dump(memory_get_usage()); // int(1717528)
$arr=range(10,10000); $obj = (object)$arr; var_dump(memory_get_usage());// int(2728048)
```

So you certainly use much more memory. If you want to reduce resources, something like this should work:

```
$object = (object)array('name' => 'John');
```

A better way could be to start with an object from the beginning:

```
$arr = new ArrayObject(array(), ArrayObject::STD_PROP_LIST);
```

Although you will have the same problem with nested arrays. If you know the structure of your array, try to extend `ArrayObject`. Or you can write your own `offsetSet()` method to implement the desired behavior. Take a look at [ArrayAccess](http://php.net/manual/en/class.arrayaccess.php).